# Customise UISegmentedControl as UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to create a `UISegmentedControl` that has same the function as `UITabBarController`.
However, I already have a `UITabBarController` in my view controller and it will be awkward if I have 2 tab bars in one view controller. So, I decided to customize the `UISegmentedControl` as a `UITabBarController`. But I really don't have any idea how to implement this.

Here is the example:

[image]

With `UISegmentedControl` I can show the `UIViewController` in ViewController.
The text is not the textview, it should be `UIViewController`.

Please help my problem.

Comment: Why don't you just hide the UITabBar ?

Comment: I just need both of them.